# Returning a file from a pssession to its invoker

Tags: powershell

It would make most sense security-wise if the answer is no, but my question originates from something like the following:

```
PS> $s = new-pssession -sshtransport -host host -user me
PS> copy-item $filename -tosession $s ${params}
PS> enter-pssession $s
[host]: PS /home> process-data $filename >process.out
[host]: PS /home> copy-item ...
```

Here I wondered if there was a way from this interactive prompt to "return" a file to my originating session. Just letting you do something like:

```
copy-item $filename -tosession $Host
```

would seem risky, I probably don't want remote scripts being able to pull things from my system.

Is there a mechanism for making a file available to the invoker, though? Something like Receive-Job, and how do I provide a file to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot transfer a file from a remote session to your session while *in* the remote session because of double-hop, but you *can* retrieve the file once you have a remote session initiated:

```
PS> $s = New-PSSession -SSHTransport -Host host -User me
PS> $filename | Copy-Item -ToSession $s -Destination /home/
PS> Enter-PSSession -Session $s

[host]: PS> process-data $filename >process.out
[host]: PS> Exit-PSSession

PS> Copy-Item -FromSession $s -Path /home/process.out -Destination C:\Temp\
```

When using the `*Session` parameters on `Copy-Item`, it uses `WinRM` to handle the file transfer instead of, say, `SMB`.  This is *more* secure.